# How can I fix a div relative to a scrollable container?

Tags: css

Please see this minimum example

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(34,193,195,1) 0%, rgba(253,187,45,1) 100%);
}

.loading-cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="loading-cover">
    Loading
  </div>
  
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to fix the white overlay when scrolling.

I've tried `inset: 0` or `width: 100%;height:100%;` on `loading-cover`, but no luck.

`position: sticky;` is also unusable in this case because it sticks to the window viewport, not the scrollable container.

Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: you have code and a gif. What is your problem?

Comment: I want to fix the white overlay when scrolling.

You can see the white overlay is not fully covered when scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the shortest path to a solution, but it does work. It might hold up in cross-browser testing if you don't need to support IE.

This is using a `loading` class on the container that applies a sticky `::before` pseudo-element, with a negative bottom margin to make the content pop up underneath it. A little goofy, but it's a weird situation. I also removed some unnecessary width values and changed `overflow` to `overflow-y`, which may or may not be useful in your situation.

With this, you could turn on and off the "Loading" message by adding or removing the class to the container.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.box {
  height: 800px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(34,193,195,1) 0%, rgba(253,187,45,1) 100%);
}

.container.loading::before {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: 'Loading';
}
```

```html
<div class="container loading">

     <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why `position: sticky` on `:before` element sticks to the parent?
That's amazing!